# Shouldn't these questions be community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

[Which food writers do you take to bed?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1710/which-food-writers-do-you-take-to-bed)

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/extraordinary-spices

Seems to me that neither of these questions could have a "right" answer. Isn't that the criteria for CW?

Answer (score 3):

Any question whose answers are submissions for a list (i.e. polls, your favorite X, list of X), the value of the answers is the accumulation and voting on the list... Those should be community wiki.

Comment: thanks for the reply. So then what's your opinion on the two questions I listed?

Comment: neveind. Saw you converted these.

Comment: We already have one cookbook thread on the go here http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/396/what-cook-books-do-you-always-come-back-to I did post this in the "take-to-bed" thread. It's just a duplicate.

Comment: @Pulse, I saw that you mentioned the dupe but didn't vote to close as one.  Any reason?  If it does get closed as a dupe, a mod or admin can always merge the answers.

Comment: @Aaronaught I wasn't 100% sure what the protocol was for dupes.

Answer (score 0):

They should *at least* be community wiki, but really they should be closed.

Do any of these topics sound like they fit the bill of [Asking Real, Expert Questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)?  They're not even questions, they're polls.  And honestly, I'm okay with the occasional poll, but we're seeing **way too many** at such an early stage.  It seems to be kind of a land grab, with different people all hoping to be the proud owner of an "historic" top-voted poll and all the associated badges.

I'm not even a true "expert" in the professional sense, but I look at these questions and go "ugh, boooo-ring."  The team has literally *begged* us in multiple places not to ask these "favourite X" questions because they're fluff and don't work well with the Q&A style of Stack Exchange.

I request an immediate moratorium on these polls so that they don't swamp the front page; once we have a steady flow of *real* questions about food and cooking, *then* we can tolerate the occasional poll.  Please help close these poll questions!

Answer (score -3):

There are very few 'right' answers in cookery - because opinion and taste form a large part of the associated body of knowledge.

I think the community wiki should be used for recipe swaps.

Comment: It hardly matters whether recipe swaps are community wiki or not; they devalue the site.  *Those* questions need to be closed as off-topic.  Poll questions in general should be immediately flagged if they're not CW (not that it will do much good until we have mods) and voted to close as NARQ by those with the privilege.

Comment: Are you serious?  Cookery is not a science.  There are no hard and fast rules.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything I said?  *(N.B. It's also wrong.  If you look at many of the highly-voted questions and answers here, they are not simply matters of taste.  Cooking is clearly subjective to a certain degree, but that does not mean anything goes.)*

Comment: I'm not sure running the site like a boot camp is going to guarantee success.  Cookery != development.